# Mysql CLI - continue execution even if the operation failed

Tags: mysql

Please consider this code:

```
    mysql -u root -p << MYSQL
        drop user '${test}'@'localhost';
        drop database ${test};

        create user '${test}'@'localhost' identified by '${psw}';
        create database ${test};
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${test}.* TO ${test}@localhost;
    MYSQL
```

The code outputs the following error for the first command `drop user '${test}'@'localhost';`:

> ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for '${test}'@'localhost'

---

### My question

How could I make the program ignores this error if it appears, so that execution doesn't break?

For example, how could I make sure the program will behavior this way:

> "Drop if you already have a user by the value of `${test}`, and if you don't, just continue to create it".

<sub>Of course, the same question goes for the second drop command dealing with the DB instance.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`IF EXISTS`** clause:

```
DROP USER IF EXISTS '${test}'@'localhost';
```

> An error occurs if you try to drop an account that does not exist. If
>   the `IF EXISTS` clause is given, the statement produces a warning for
>   each named user that does not exist, rather than an error.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-user.html

Answer (score 2):

You could also [force the `mysql` tool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/batch-mode.html) to ignore errors on all commands:

> If you want the script to continue even if some of the statements in it produce errors, you should use the `--force` command-line option.

i.e. `mysql --force -u root -p  << ...`

Comment: @Arcticooling, no, sorry, I was too brief, edited.

Comment: Hmm, I assume it will runover/runthrough the sexisting once already created with the same name (in case I created them manually before executing my above code).